# subject in "participle phrase"

Tags: subject-complement

> The quality of products can improve by using robots.

In this sentence, what is the subject of "using"?
I think it should rephrase

> The quality of products can be improved by using robots.

Or

> The quality of products can be improved with correct use of robots".

Comment: Like most non-finite clauses, the gerund-participial clause "using robots" is subjectless, although we understand it as if it did (even if the subject may be understood to be "some arbitrary person").

Comment: Using robots can give rise to job loss. The subject there is using robots. In your sentence, it does not have a subject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first sentence is not grammatical.  Your first revision is almost correct -- you're just missing a "the" in front of "products".  Or you can simply say

> Product quality can be improved by using robots

Your second sentence is also not quite right, as it should be "**the** correct use of robots".

Also I think "the appropriate use" or "the effective use" sounds better than "correct use", because we are talking about how to use robots for this particular *application*, and not whether any existing robots are used *correctly*.